# web role access sql azure in same data center

Tags: azure-sql-database

I published my web role in windows azure which is accessing a SQL azure in same data center. According to Microsoft, above model should be called "Code Near Connectivity" and the connection between web role and SQL azure will not over internet but internally. See details at page http://programming4.us/database/1078.aspx#HPXtedlpJh3o1l1H.99

I wonder the Code-Near-Connection will be auto made by windows azure or anything needed to be applied first to make it happen.

Answer (score 3):

It is automatic as long as you have selected to deployment of your code and sql db in the same region.

Comment: Thanks. Is the connection between web role and sql internally? I still use "server=xxx.database.windows.net" to access the server. My concern is whether I still need to use SSL between them for a Code-Near-Connection.

Comment: Web Role and SQL Azure are still different cloud services (although from the same provider), therefore, you should not assume "internal" communication. The Code-Near-Connection is a design optimization principle to improve the performance, but if you are using multiple services, you should always treat them as independent.